# AlertConfirmation, javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Im doing this assignment where I make a comboBox filled with bagel varieties and another filled with cream cheese variety in order to add or delete items a radioButton must be selected. I got mostly everything to work except this AlertConfirmation part. Where if i click yes it will delete and if i click no it wont delete the items. It works when i click no it doesnt delete and does everything right but when i click yes delete, the Alert stays on until i press no again.
I am using JavaFx14.

```
public int deleteItem() 
    {
        int indexInteger = 0;
        String deleteString;
  
    if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        indexInteger = bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        deleteString = (String) bagelComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);
        
        if(indexInteger != -1 && indexInteger != 0)
        {
            alertMethod();
            AlertDialog("","","");
            bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        }
        
    }
    if(creamRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        indexInteger = creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        deleteString = (String) creamComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);
        
        if(indexInteger != -1 && indexInteger != 0)
        {
            alertMethod();
            AlertDialog("","","");
            creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            
        }
        
    }
        
    return indexInteger;
    
}

public void alertMethod() {
    String outPutListString;
    boolean confirmBoolean = false;
    
    outPutListString = "Do you wish to delete this Item?";
    
    confirmBoolean = AlertConformation("", "Yes or No", outPutListString);

        
    if(confirmBoolean) {
        if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) 
        {
            bagelComboBox.getItems().remove(deleteItem());
            
        }
        else
        {
            creamComboBox.getItems().remove(deleteItem());
            
        }
            
    }
    else {
        
        addDialog("","","Nothing Was Deleted");
        bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }
}
public boolean AlertConformation(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString) 
    {
        boolean confirmBoolean = false;
        
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle(titleString);
        alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
        alert.setContentText(messageString);
        
        ButtonType yesButton = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonBar.ButtonData.YES);
        ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.NO);
        
        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(yesButton, noButton);
        
        Optional <ButtonType> resultButtonType = alert.showAndWait();
        
        if(resultButtonType.get() == yesButton) {
            confirmBoolean = true;
        }
        
        return confirmBoolean;
    }
```

this is all the code.

```
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 *
 * @
 */
public class BagelStop extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
    // create the GridPaneObject
    GridPane mainGridPane = new GridPane();
    Label companyNameLabel = new Label("Bagel Stop");
    TextField addTextField = new TextField();
    Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    Button deleteButton = new Button("Del.");
    Button displayButton = new Button("Display");
    ToggleGroup foodToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
  //Bagel observablelist and comboBox
    ObservableList<String> bagelTypeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Bagels", "Plain" , "Egg" , "Rye", "Salt" , "Blueberry" , "Garlic", "Onion", "Sesame", "Poppy Seed");
    ComboBox<String> bagelComboBox = new ComboBox<String>(bagelTypeList);
    RadioButton bagelRadioButton = new RadioButton();
    
    ObservableList<String> creamCheeseList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("CreamCheese", "Plain" , "Herb","Garlic");
    ComboBox<String> creamComboBox = new ComboBox<String>(creamCheeseList);
    RadioButton creamRadioButton = new RadioButton();
    
    
    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
    public BagelStop(){
        // Call these methods
        designClass();
        addAction();
    }
    
    
    public void designClass()
    {
        //Scene design
        mainGridPane.setHgap(10);
        mainGridPane.setVgap(10);
        mainGridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        companyNameLabel.setFont(Font.font(" Monaco", 30));
        companyNameLabel.setTextFill(Color.DARKOLIVEGREEN);
        
        bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        
        bagelRadioButton.setToggleGroup(foodToggleGroup);
        creamRadioButton.setToggleGroup(foodToggleGroup);
        
        mainGridPane.add(companyNameLabel, 2, 0);
        mainGridPane.add(bagelComboBox, 1, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(bagelRadioButton, 0, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(creamComboBox, 3, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(creamRadioButton, 4, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(addTextField, 2, 2);
       
        mainGridPane.add(addButton, 2, 4);
        mainGridPane.add(deleteButton, 2, 5);
        mainGridPane.add(displayButton, 2, 6);
    }
    
    
    public void addAction() {
        addButton.setOnAction(this);
        deleteButton.setOnAction(this);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        Object sourceObject = event.getSource();

        if(sourceObject == addButton) 
        {
            addItem();
        }
        else if(sourceObject== deleteButton) 
        {
            deleteItem();
        }
        else {
            display();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void display() {
        
    }
    
    ////
    public int deleteItem() 
    {
        int indexInteger = 0;
        String deleteString;
  
        if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            indexInteger = bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            deleteString = (String) bagelComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);
            
            if(indexInteger != -1 && indexInteger != 0)
            {
                alertMethod();
                AlertDialog("","","");
                bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            }
            
        }
        if(creamRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            indexInteger = creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            deleteString = (String) creamComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);
            
            if(indexInteger != -1 && indexInteger != 0)
            {
                alertMethod();
                AlertDialog("","","");
                creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                
            }
            
        }
            
        return indexInteger;
        
    }
    
    public void alertMethod() {
        String outPutListString;
        boolean confirmBoolean = false;
        
        outPutListString = "Do you wish to delete this Item?";
        
        confirmBoolean = AlertConformation("", "Yes or No", outPutListString);
    
            
        if(confirmBoolean) {
            if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) 
            {
                bagelComboBox.getItems().remove(deleteItem());
                
            }
            else
            {
                creamComboBox.getItems().remove(deleteItem());
                
            }
                
        }
        else {
            
            addDialog("","","Nothing Was Deleted");
            bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        }
    }
                    

    
    ////
    public void addItem() {
        
        String foodString = addTextField.getText();
        boolean foundBoolean = false;
        int indexInteger = 0;
        String checkString;
        
        if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            while(!foundBoolean && indexInteger < bagelComboBox.getItems().size())
            {
                
                checkString = (String)bagelComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);  

                if(foodString.equalsIgnoreCase(checkString)){
                    
                    foundBoolean = true;
                }
                else
                {
                         indexInteger++;
                }
            }
            if (foundBoolean)

            {
                  AlertDialog(foodString,"Food","This food item is already in the list");
                  
                  addTextField.setText("");
                  
            }
            else
            {
                bagelTypeList.addAll(foodString);
                addDialog(foodString,"","This food item is added to the list");
                addTextField.setText("");
            }
        }
        if(creamRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            while(!foundBoolean && indexInteger < creamComboBox.getItems().size()) {
                
                checkString =(String)creamComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);

                if(foodString.equalsIgnoreCase(checkString))

                {
                     foundBoolean = true;
                }
                else
                {
                     indexInteger++;
                }
                
            }
            if (foundBoolean)

            {
                  AlertDialog(foodString,"Food","This food item is already in the list");
                  addTextField.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                creamCheeseList.addAll(foodString);
                addDialog(foodString,"","This food item is added to the list");
                addTextField.setText("");
            }

        }
            
    }
    
    
    
   
    
    
    public boolean AlertConformation(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString) 
    {
        boolean confirmBoolean = false;
        
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle(titleString);
        alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
        alert.setContentText(messageString);
        
        ButtonType yesButton = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonBar.ButtonData.YES);
        ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.NO);
        
        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(yesButton, noButton);
        
        Optional <ButtonType> resultButtonType = alert.showAndWait();
        
        if(resultButtonType.get() == yesButton) {
            confirmBoolean = true;
        }
        
        return confirmBoolean;
    }
    
    
    public void AlertDialog(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString)
    {
       Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
       alert.setTitle(titleString);
       alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
       alert.setContentText(messageString);
       alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public void addDialog(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString)
    {
       Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
       alert.setTitle(titleString);
       alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
       alert.setContentText(messageString);
       alert.showAndWait();
    }

    
    

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bagel Stop");
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainGridPane, 500,700);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }

    
}
```

Comment: I would prefer a true [mcve] , but this is the first question I am looking at this morning that asks a clear question, and includes your own efforts. So have my upvote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer this is the new code look at the deleteitem method

```
    import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 *
 * @author eduardo_gamboacruz
 */
public class BagelStop extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
    // create the GridPaneObject
    GridPane mainGridPane = new GridPane();
    Label companyNameLabel = new Label("Bagel Stop");
    TextField addTextField = new TextField();
    Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    Button deleteButton = new Button("Del.");
    Button displayButton = new Button("Display");
    ToggleGroup foodToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
  //Bagel observablelist and comboBox
    ObservableList<String> bagelTypeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Bagels", "Plain" , "Egg" , "Rye", "Salt" , "Blueberry" , "Garlic", "Onion", "Sesame", "Poppy Seed");
    ComboBox<String> bagelComboBox = new ComboBox<String>(bagelTypeList);
    RadioButton bagelRadioButton = new RadioButton();
    
    ObservableList<String> creamCheeseList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("CreamCheese", "Plain" , "Herb","Garlic");
    ComboBox<String> creamComboBox = new ComboBox<String>(creamCheeseList);
    RadioButton creamRadioButton = new RadioButton();
    
    
    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
    public BagelStop(){
        // Call these methods
        designClass();
        addAction();
    }
    
    
    public void designClass()
    {
        //Scene design
        mainGridPane.setHgap(10);
        mainGridPane.setVgap(10);
        mainGridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        companyNameLabel.setFont(Font.font(" Monaco", 30));
        companyNameLabel.setTextFill(Color.DARKOLIVEGREEN);
        
        bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        
        bagelRadioButton.setToggleGroup(foodToggleGroup);
        creamRadioButton.setToggleGroup(foodToggleGroup);
        
        mainGridPane.add(companyNameLabel, 2, 0);
        mainGridPane.add(bagelComboBox, 1, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(bagelRadioButton, 0, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(creamComboBox, 3, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(creamRadioButton, 4, 1);
        mainGridPane.add(addTextField, 2, 2);
       
        mainGridPane.add(addButton, 2, 4);
        mainGridPane.add(deleteButton, 2, 5);
        mainGridPane.add(displayButton, 2, 6);
    }
    
    
    public void addAction() {
        addButton.setOnAction(this);
        deleteButton.setOnAction(this);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        Object sourceObject = event.getSource();

        if(sourceObject == addButton) 
        {
            addItem();
        }
        else if(sourceObject== deleteButton) 
        {
            deleteItem();
        }
        else {
            display();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void display() {
        
    }
    
    ////
    public void deleteItem() 
    {
        int indexInteger = 0;
        String deleteString = null;
        String outPutListString;
        boolean confirmBoolean = false;
        
        outPutListString = "Do you wish to delete this Item?";
        confirmBoolean = AlertConformation("", outPutListString , deleteString);
  
        if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            
            indexInteger = bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            deleteString = (String) bagelComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);
            
            if(indexInteger != -1 && indexInteger != 0){
                
                if(confirmBoolean) {
                    
                    bagelComboBox.getItems().remove(indexInteger);
                    
                }
                else {
                    addDialog("","","Nothing Was Deleted");
                    bagelComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(creamRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            
            indexInteger = creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            deleteString = (String) creamComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);
            
            if(indexInteger != -1 && indexInteger != 0){
                
                if(confirmBoolean) {
                    
                    creamComboBox.getItems().remove(indexInteger);
                    
                }
                else {
                    addDialog("","","Nothing Was Deleted");
                    creamComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
                    

    
    ////
    public void addItem() {
        
        String foodString = addTextField.getText();
        boolean foundBoolean = false;
        int indexInteger = 0;
        String checkString;
        
        if(bagelRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            while(!foundBoolean && indexInteger < bagelComboBox.getItems().size())
            {
                
                checkString = (String)bagelComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);  

                if(foodString.equalsIgnoreCase(checkString)){
                    
                    foundBoolean = true;
                }
                else
                {
                         indexInteger++;
                }
            }
            if (foundBoolean)

            {
                  AlertDialog(foodString,"Food","This food item is already in the list");
                  
                  addTextField.setText("");
                  
            }
            else
            {
                bagelTypeList.addAll(foodString);
                addDialog(foodString,"","This food item is added to the list");
                addTextField.setText("");
            }
        }
        if(creamRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            while(!foundBoolean && indexInteger < creamComboBox.getItems().size()) {
                
                checkString =(String)creamComboBox.getItems().get(indexInteger);

                if(foodString.equalsIgnoreCase(checkString))

                {
                     foundBoolean = true;
                }
                else
                {
                     indexInteger++;
                }
                
            }
            if (foundBoolean)

            {
                  AlertDialog(foodString,"Food","This food item is already in the list");
                  addTextField.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                creamCheeseList.addAll(foodString);
                addDialog(foodString,"","This food item is added to the list");
                addTextField.setText("");
            }

        }
            
    }
    
    
    
   
    
    
    public boolean AlertConformation(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString) 
    {
        boolean confirmBoolean = false;
        
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle(titleString);
        alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
        alert.setContentText(messageString);
        
        ButtonType yesButton = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonBar.ButtonData.YES);
        ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.NO);
        
        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(yesButton, noButton);
        
        Optional <ButtonType> resultButtonType = alert.showAndWait();
        
        if(resultButtonType.get() == yesButton) {
            confirmBoolean = true;
        }
        
        return confirmBoolean;
    }
    
    
    public void AlertDialog(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString)
    {
       Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
       alert.setTitle(titleString);
       alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
       alert.setContentText(messageString);
       alert.showAndWait();
    }

    public void addDialog(String titleString, String headerString, String messageString)
    {
       Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
       alert.setTitle(titleString);
       alert.setHeaderText(headerString);
       alert.setContentText(messageString);
       alert.showAndWait();
    }

    
    

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bagel Stop");
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainGridPane, 500,700);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }


    

    
    
}
```

Comment: It would be best to explain the new code in your answer. It's not necessarily easy to spot the differences between the code in your question and the code in your answer.